# Issue in Cordova - ionic background mode plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using background mode plugin in my project.

I want to insert the Geolocation of a device into database when the device is on [deviceready mode].

When the user switches to [background/pause] mode the device's geolocation will not be inserted to the database.

The geolocation is inserted to the database every three seconds.

When I switch the device mode to [background] mode it keeps inserting geolocation to the database.

What's the problem?

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);
var globLat;
var globLong;
var db = null;

app.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    if (cordova.platformId === "ios" && window.cordova && window.cordova
      .plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }

    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    db = window.openDatabase("mobileDB", "1.0", "Cordova Demo",
      200000);
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coords (latDB float , longDB float)"
    );
    /*
    var query = "INSERT INTO coords (latDB, longDB) VALUES (?,?)";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [globLat, globLong]); */

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {

      setInterval(function () {
        var query =
          "INSERT INTO coords (latDB, longDB) VALUES (?,?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [globLat, globLong]);

      }, 3000);
    }

  });

})

app.controller('GeoCtrl', function ($cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaSQLite) {

  var posOptions = {
    timeout: 10000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false
  };
  $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude

      globLat = lat;
      globLong = long;

      // alert("latitude is : " + globLat + "and longitude is :" + globLong);

    }).then(
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {
          lat: globLat,
          lng: globLong
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 18,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      });
});
```

Note:

I used Visual Studio 2015 ripple emulator to switch the device mode 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All `onDeviceReady()` does is check if the device is ready, so even though its in the background it'll still be inserted because its a a plugin for getting geolocation in (you guessed it) the background. Use http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/ instead as it suits your needs more appropriately.

Comment: Yes  but i  am already using geolocation plugin . 

i need the geolocation only inserted when the device is  on the background mode  ..

Comment: Then please put the full code, the code above did not make mention to which was being used and how it's being used.

Comment: Is this for Android, have you tried IOS? I have a situation where my Android App keeps running in the background like it's in the foreground. Can you test on the actual devices and relay back to me please